# Django Rest Framework Constant URL for Images

Tags: django, image, api, rest, url

I want all my uploaded images to go /media/ so I can easily reroute URLs to /media/.  One example is when I upload images I set the upload path to /images/credentials so I would like it to save to /media/images/credentials/.  And it does save there properly.  When a user uploads an image, it goes to my proper /media/images/credentials folder on my computer.

However when the API serves up that image later (the API is located at /api/v1/members/credentials it goes to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/members/credentials/images/credentials/.  What I would like to do is remove the first part, the api/v1/members/credentials.  The problem is it forces my URL's file to be as below:

```
if base.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
                            (r'^api/v1/members/credentials/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
                                'document_root': base.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

Which only works for this one API.  But I'd like to have one urlpattern entry for all images for all API URLs.  I would rather all image links when served back to the user not include the API portion so I don't have to make a separate urlpattern entry for each API.  I have many APIs which serve images, not just /credentials/.

Model is this:

```
class Credential(models.Model):
    """Used to store various credentials for member validation."""
    document_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=get_upload_path(instance="instance",
                                  filename="filename.ext",
                                  path='images/credentials/'))
```

Settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "sailistio", "media")
```

Other relevant URL entries:

base URLS:

```
url(r'^api/v1/members/', include(members_urls, namespace="members")),
```

Member URLs:

```
url(r'^credentials/$', views.UserCredentialList.as_view(), name='user-credential-list'),
```

Thank you for any help!

Edit:

```
class UserCredentialList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsCredentialOwnerOrAdmin,)
    serializer_class = CredentialSerializer

    """
    This view should return a list of all the purchases
    for the currently authenticated user.
    """

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all models by
        the maker passed in the URL
        """
        user = self.request.user
        return Credential.objects.filter(member=user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(member_id=self.request.user.id)
```

And here is this in case you need it:

```
class CredentialSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Credential
        fields = (
            'id',
            'credential_type',
            'credential_number',
            'date_received',
            'is_verified',
            'date_verified',
            'document_image',
        )

    def is_valid(self, raise_exception=False):
        imageHandler = ImageHandler()
        self._kwargs["data"]["document_image"] = imageHandler.convertImage(self._kwargs["data"]["document_image"])
        return super(CredentialSerializer, self).is_valid()
```

Comment: Show me your `UserCredentialList`

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer...

There is a MEDIA_URL setting that I needed to set to '/media/' in my base config file.